# Should editing fstab change systemd mountpoint service file?

Tags: systemd, mount, fstab

I edited my `/etc/fstab` to mount with `x-systemd.device-timeout=15`:

```
UUID=a115a456-1fb7-4ae1-9bfd-504d47d1f780 /mnt/hdd ext4 rw,auto,defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=15 0 2
```

I was wondering if this should be then visible under `Options` with `systemctl edit --full mnt-hdd.mount`:

```
1 # Automatically generated by systemd-fstab-generator
 2
 3 [Unit]
 4 SourcePath=/etc/fstab
 5 Documentation=man:fstab(5) man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
 6 Requires=systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-a115a456\x2d1fb7\x2d4ae1\x2d9bfd\x2d504d47d1f780.service
 7 After=systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-a115a456\x2d1fb7\x2d4ae1\x2d9bfd\x2d504d47d1f780.service
 8
 9 [Mount]
10 Where=/mnt/hdd
11 What=/dev/disk/by-uuid/a115a456-1fb7-4ae1-9bfd-504d47d1f780
12 Type=ext4
13 Options=rw,auto,defaults,nofail
```

As I am experiencing problems that might be related to my fstab not waiting for the mount to come up I was wondering if there is some error here.

---

### More details:

This is my `/etc/fstab`:

```
...

UUID=a115a456-1fb7-4ae1-9bfd-504d47d1f780 /mnt/hdd ext4 rw,auto,defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=15 0 2
UUID=e3f9d42a-9703-4e47-9185-33be24b81c46 /mnt/mybook ext4 rw,auto,defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=15 0 2
    
#mp3fs#/mnt/mybook/test/NEUE-MUSIK-FLAC /mnt/hdd/mp3fs/mp3fs-neue-musik fuse allow_other,ro,bitrate=192 0 0
```

As you can see I am mounting two external USB harddrives. One of them (`mybook`) contains folders with `FLAC` music. This music is mounted as `mp3` with the awesome `mp3fs` [filesystem](https://khenriks.github.io/mp3fs/) so I can access my `FLAC` files as `mp3`. I don't do this mount on the `mybook` because this harddrive will get backed up regularly.

Instead I mount the `mp3` somewhere else. The problem now seems to be that the harddrive `mybook` is usually asleep and needs some time to wake up. This will break the mount of the `mp3fs` and due to that (I assume) my boot will then stuck. I had this issue two times now and fixed it by commenting all `fstab` mounts.

That is why I tried to add a `timeout` to the mount. I refered to the timeout of `hdd`, because it needs to be mounted to provide the folder structure for `mp3fs`. On the other hand, `mybook` needs to be mounted to provide the source files.

So, on both mounts I put the timeout. **But it is not shown in the according `systemd` mount file.** Since also my boot does not work with this timeout setting and the `mp3fs` I assume the timeout is not really used. **The mounts will be there when I access the system via `ssh`. But I have no way of checking, if the mounts are online at the time the `mp3fs` filesystem mount needs them.**

Comment: There's a systemd-fstab-generator that generates the unit file from /etc/fstab; did you reboot or run that generator after making the change to /etc/fstab?

Comment: I did reboot, but reboot was not successfull. I think the boot failed because I tried to mount `mp3fs`filesystem on a mountpoint that was not yet ready due to a slow USB HDD waking up. That's why I added the systemd timeout of 15 seconds which should be enough. But the boot failed with that timeout also. So maybe something did not generate correctly? Should I be able to run the generator manually?

Comment: I did a `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` but still no change. Maybe it is not supposed to be under `Options=`.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what the problem is, and what's happening. Your question mentions /mnt/hdd, but your recent comment refers to a failure of an mp3fs filesystem and a USB HDD. Systemd should, IMHO, not mount a filesystem until it has run the fsck (see in the Requires and After), but I wouldn't expect one missing device or filesystem to halt the boot.

Comment: I added more information at the bottom. I am pretty sure `mp3fs` breaks the boot when one or both hdds are not mounted. When an `ext4` mount has no `nofail` option it also will break the boot.

Comment: Just as a random opinion, I wonder if you'd prefer to have it be automounted.

Comment: Well it is automounted at boot if you are referring to the two HDDs. The `mp3fs` is commented at the moment because if not it will break the boot.

Comment: Sorry; I meant an [automounter that mounts it on-demand](https://linux.die.net/man/8/automount)